# Print arrays in Perl

Tags: perl

I am using Perl in Ubuntu. I have assigned few values to an array and when I am printing the array it is giving some HASH values.

Can anybody assist me with this?

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $VAR="you are welcome";
my @arr={'1','2','3','4'};
print @arr;
print $VAR."\n";
print "$$ \n";
```

Here is the output

```
HASH(0x140cd80)you are welcome 
12548
```

Comment: `{}` indicates a hashref. Use `my @arr=('1','2','3','4');` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for your precious help

Answer (score 9):

`{ ... }` generates an anonymous hash, and you have assigned the hash `{ 1 => '2', 3 => '4' }` to the first and only element of `@arr`.

To set `@arr` to have four elements containg one through four, you must write

```
my @arr = ( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

or

```
my @arr = 1 .. 4;
```

and then `print @arr` will output `1234`.

If you want to put spaces between the array elements you can just put the array inside double quotes. `print "@arr"` will output `1 2 3 4`

Comment: and some features about `$"=qq(\n)` <- varialbe 'list-separator'

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other ways you can use formatting when printing an array in Perl:

```
print join(", ", @arr);
```

or

```
$" = ", ";
print "@arr\n";
```